# Select within select for MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to SELECT specific lines of data from a MYSQL database

The database is as follows

```
Count   id     Startstation      stp
1      A1234   Nottingham         o
2      A1234   Nottingham         p
3      B2345   Nottingham         p
4      C6789   Leeds              o
```

I would like to select all the Nottingham stations but not repeat the same id. Also an stp code of o takes priority over an stp of p.

So I am  looking for an output as follows:

```
A1234   Nottingham         o
B2345   Nottingham         p
```

Here is the code I have been trying to use but I cannot get it to work

```
require('connect_db.php');
mysqli_select_db($mysql_link,"timetable");               
$q="select * from (SELECT id,startstation, stp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY stp  DESC) rnk FROM railtest WHERE startstation="Nottingham") where rnk = 1";

$r=mysqli_query($mysql_link,$q);
if ($r)
{                                       
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo $row['startstation'] . " " . $row['id']." ".$row['stp'];
echo "<br>";                
}               
}
else {echo '<p>'.mysqli_error($mysql_link).'</p>' ;}                        
mysqli_close($mysql_link);
```

I am getting a Parse error with my select statement

Hope some one can help

Thanks

Comment: Try this: `select distinct id,Startstation,stp from table where Startstation = 'Nottingham' order by stp asc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`,`startstation`,min(`stp`) as stp
FROM `railtest`
WHERE `startstation`='Nottingham'
GROUP BY `id`, `startstation`
```

Group on the two columns that are the same and since `o` comes before `p` you can just select the `min` value. Obviously this works when there are two values for stp, more and you can put them alphabetically by priority or use a correlated sub-query to get the value for stp.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id`,`startstation`, `stp`
FROM `railtest`
WHERE `startstation`='Nottingham'
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER BY `stp` ASC
```

Comment: Won't this return two rows when there are two different values for `stp`? A `distinct` typically means that every column needs to be unique for the row to be considered unique. In the example data given, rows 1, 2 and 3 will be returned when OP just wants 1 and 3.

Comment: This did return both id's of A1234 instead of just one